# Updating via SSH: Magento CE 2.1.2 to 2.1.3

Tags: upgrade, magento-2.1.2, command-line, ssh, magento-2.1.3

I would like to update my Magento 2.1.2 version to the new Magento 2.1.3 via SSH.
I have established a connection with my server, but am not sure how to continue.

The internet provides me commands on how to update from 2.0.x to 2.1.x, but I do not know how to change these such that they perform the desired 2.1.2 to 2.1.3 update.

Also, it seems that the commands needed differ depending wether or not my Magento was originally installed with sample data. I cannot remember if my version was installed with sample data.

**Commands found**

*without sample data*

**1** composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0 --no-update
 
**2** Composer update 
**3** php bin/magento setup:upgrade

*with sample data*

**1** composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0 --no-update
 
**2** composer require magento/module-bundle-sample-data:100.1.0 magento/module-widget-sample-data:100.1.0 magento/module-theme-sample-data:100.1.0 magento/module-catalog-sample-data:100.1.0 magento/module-customer-sample-data:100.1.0 magento/module-cms-sample-data:100.1.0 magento/module-catalog-rule-sample-data:100.1.0 magento/module-sales-rule-sample-data:100.1.0 magento/module-review-sample-data:100.1.0 magento/module-tax-sample-data:100.1.0 magento/module-sales-sample-data:100.1.0 magento/module-grouped-product-sample-data:100.1.0 magento/module-downloadable-sample-data:100.1.0 magento/module-msrp-sample-data:100.1.0 magento/module-configurable-sample-data:100.1.0 magento/module-product-links-sample-data:100.1.0 magento/module-wishlist-sample-data:100.1.0 magento/module-swatches-sample-data:100.1.0 magento/sample-data-media:100.1.0 magento/module-offline-shipping-sample-data:100.1.0 --no-update
**3** Composer update 
**4** php bin/magento setup:upgrade

In concrete, my questions are,

- How do I figure out wether or not I initially installed with sample data?
- How do I change the above commands such that I obtain the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

You can find out if you have sample data installed by running `composer show`. You'll see a list of all the composer installed modules.

Installing to 2.1.3:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.3 --no-update
composer update
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Some advice: don't upgrade to 2.1.3 just yet, we're experincing a lot of new bugs. Check out the issue's on the M2 Github repo https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the advice. How long would you wait before updating – 1 day/week/month?

Comment: Just keep an eye on the Magento 2 repo and decide if you still want to upgrade. You can also skip this version and wait for magento 2.1.4 or 2.2